# why i fail to create this table on android SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created 4 table on my app. 
Below is the creation of the last table -

this is the query that i get after the parse of the string

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( PK_Person ) REFERENCES TABLE_2 , COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY( COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT ) REFERENCES TABLE_3 );

When i run this method of creation - i get an exception that the value near the COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT is

Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (near "COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT ": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..... ( the query )

I check and all the table that i create before this table are exist.

```
  try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();



String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_1 + "("
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                + "PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( PK_Person )" + " REFERENCES " + TABLE_2 + ", "
                + COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT  + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY( " +  COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_3 + " );";




db.execSQL(query);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL as understood by sqlite, table constrainsts such as `FOREIGN KEY` follow column specifiations. You cannot intermix them. Move the `FOREIGN KEY` specs at the end of your `CREATE TABLE` so that the `COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT` column spec is before them.

Comment: but i add the specific table that i want to foreign to ( with the column ) - and i created it

Answer (score 0):

You should create or call create on the referenced tables first before creating this table with multiple foreign keys.

I tested the query by using SQLiteOpenHelper class see below:

```
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASENAME = "eeee.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_1 = "tb1";
    private static final String TABLE_2 = "tb2";
    private static final String TABLE_3 = "tb3";
    private static final String COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT = "indexxx";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String mainquery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_1 + "("
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                + "PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( PK_Person )" + " REFERENCES " + TABLE_2 + ", "
                + COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT  + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY( " +  COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_3 + " );";

        String query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_2 + "("
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                + "PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL );";

        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_3 + "("
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                + COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT  + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query2);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(mainquery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
// you can specify your own implementation here if db version incremented
    }
}
```

Comment: i did create the table before

Comment: heirarchy on code, call the creating of table of the other two first did you?.

Comment: yes yes yes .. i did - i created and i also check if it been done by add some element into those table

Comment: @Yanshof I edited answer above and tested the code you have wrapping it inside an SQLiteOpenHelper and there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code:

```
String mainquery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_1 + "("
            + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
            + "PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( PK_Person )" + " REFERENCES " + TABLE_2 + ", "
            + COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT  + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY( " +  COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_3 + " );";
```

add a references to table,but not found column name. you can try:

```
 String mainquery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_1 + "("
            + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
            + "PK_Person TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( PK_Person )" + " REFERENCES " + TABLE_2 + ", "
            + COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT  + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY( " +  COLUMN_INDEX_AS_TEXT + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_3 + "("+COLUMN_NAME+")" );";
```