# SQLite Create Table Syntax Error [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having issues with creating a db using SQLite in my Android project. The issue is creating the COL_TASK_DESC and COL_TASK_DATE as my spacing is not correct. Because of that I've not been able to create my table.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382970/why-i-fail-to-create-this-table-on-android-sqlite) but still have not been able to see what is wrong with my spacing.

Can anyone see what I'm not seeing?

Thanks,

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + Task.GrabTask.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Task.GrabTask._ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Task.GrabTask.COL_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + Task.GrabTask.COL_TASK_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Task.GrabTask.COL_TASK_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    Log.i("SQL_CREATE", sql);

    // Create the db
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Task.GrabTask._ID` be `Task.GrabTask.COL_ID`? Check your constants definition.

Comment: All looks fine from what you've shown, can you edit your post to include where the Task.grab.???? variables are set (i.e. what they are set to). If you have by any chance added any columns then deleting or clearing (same thing just different terms used) the App's data (settings/apps) or uninstalling the App (assuming you can afford to lose any current data) and then re-rerunning the App may resolve the issue (i.e. `onCreate` only runs when a database doesn't exist, delete the App's data deletes the database thus `onCreate` will run, perhaps the most common reason why columns are not found).

Comment: An indication of the issue with `onCreate`/changed structure (new columns) would be that nothing is output to the log by `Log.i("SQL_CREATE", sql);`.